# Javascript - after ajax call, some of the variables no longer defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

This is really strange to me. After AJAX call, some of the variables are no longer defined. Some are, some are not. Why?

If you look at the sentence 'THIS IS THE POINT WHERE I NEED MY VARIABLES' - at this point:

- cMobile is defined and value is in it
- cShowAlertsDesktopApp is also defined and has value in it
- cIN_SRT is defined and has value in it

**- $divMessage is not defined. But it was defined before ajax call. Why is that? How can I use this variable in return from ajax?**

```
var DeleteTableJEREIN = function (e, iREIN_KEY) {

    var cMobile = $("#cMobileApplication").val();
    var cShowAlertsDesktopApp = $("#hiddenShowAlertsDesktopApp").val();

    if (!confirm("Izbrišem?")) {
      return;
    }

    var cIN_SRT = $("#hidden_hIN_SRT").val();
    var $divMessage = $(e).closest('td').find('div.divMessage');

    $.ajax({
      url: '/Warehouse/InsertUpdateJEREIN/',
      type: 'POST',
      data: {
        iREIN_KEY: iREIN_KEY,
        cTask: '4'
      },
      success: function (msg) {

**THIS IS THE POINT WHERE I NEED MY VARIABLES**

        var json = JSON.parse(msg);

        if (json.error) {

          if (cMobile === "1") {
            fInventoryShippingReceiving.HideMessages();
```

Comment: Try with `bind`

Comment: Can you try to access to the variable "e" in the success of the ajax call? I believe that is the cause of the problem, when you try to access $divMessage the variable e is undefined and this doesn't return anything thats why you are seeing divMessage as undefined.

Comment: True - e is not defined. But why? How can I transfer e to ajax?

Comment: @DananjayaAriyasena - can you provide example?

Comment: FrenkyB are you sure you are not making any typos? When I paste "foo = $(e).closest('td').find('div.divMessage')" to console then "foo === undefined" Is false (mind that "e" is undefined as well).

Comment: It seems to be a context issue, try bind or arrow function in order to bind context

Comment: Given the code you've added the only way they would be undefined is if they we're undefined originally if that's not true then there is something in your code that you've not added. Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/) of your problem